# Prove that $\sqrt x$ is Lipschitz on $[1, \infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Prove that $\sqrt x$ is Lipschitz on $[1, \infty)$

I want to show that $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq L |x - y|$

So $|\sqrt x  - \sqrt y| = \frac{|x - y|}{\sqrt x + \sqrt y} \leq \frac{1}{2}|x - y|$.

I can see that to get $|\sqrt x  - \sqrt y| = \frac{|x - y|}{\sqrt x + \sqrt y}$ I just multiply the first expression by its conjugate. But I don't really understand how $\frac{|x - y|}{\sqrt x + \sqrt y} \leq \frac{1}{2}|x - y|$ How does $\frac{1}{\sqrt x + \sqrt y} \leq \frac{1}{2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more general way to do this would be to note that $f'(x) = \frac 1{2\sqrt x}$; and since $f'(x) < 1/2$ if $ x > 1$, you have that $f(x) = \sqrt x $ is Lipschitz continuos.

This stems from the mean value theorem; for $x, y \in [1, \infty)$ there exists $c \in [x,y]$ such that $f(x) - f(y) = f'(c) (x-y)$. Taking the modulus to both sides and since $f'(c) < \frac 12$, you have that $$\left|f(x) - f(y)\right| \le \frac 12 \left|x-y\right|$$

Answer (score 1):

We know $x,y \in [1, \infty)$ thus both $x,y \geq 1$.

Now we can see $$\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} \geq 1 + 1 =2$$
and so we know $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}} \leq \frac{1}{2}$$
because both values are positive.

Hence all that remains for us is to multiply through by $|x-y|$ and we get $$\frac{|x-y|}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}} \leq \frac{|x-y|}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

---

If $x$ and $y$ are both at least $1$, then $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}\geq1+1=2$. Taking reciprocals gives you the desired inequality.